# how to display time first followed by date in ICS

Tags: php, icalendar

I am using ICS file for my app it showing correct date and time (e.g.Sat Nov 7, 2014 11:50am (IST)) but i want to display time first followed by date (e.g. 11:50am sat 7th Nov, 2014 (IST)) how to do this?

```
class ICS{

function __construct(){

}

function generateICS($timestamp_start, $timestamp_end, $subject, $address, $description, $event_url){

    $datestr_start = $this->dateToCal($timestamp_start);
    $datestr_end = $this->dateToCal($timestamp_end);
    $datestr_current = $this->dateToCal(date('U'));

    $esc_subject = $this->escapeString($subject);
    $esc_address = $this->escapeString($address);
    $esc_description = $this->escapeString($description);
    $esc_url = $this->escapeString($event_url);

    $uniqid = uniqid();

    $ics = <<<ICS
   BEGIN:VCALENDAR
   VERSION:2.0
   PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
   CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
   BEGIN:VEVENT
   DTEND:$datestr_end
   UID:$uniqid
   DTSTAMP:$datestr_current
   LOCATION:$address
   DESCRIPTION:$esc_description
   URL;VALUE=URI:$esc_url
   SUMMARY:$esc_subject
   DTSTART:$datestr_start
   END:VEVENT
   END:VCALENDAR
   ICS;
        return $ics;
   }

 function dateToCal($timestamp) {
   return gmdate('Ymd\THis', $timestamp);
 }

function escapeString($string) {
  return preg_replace('/([\,;])/','\\\$1', $string);
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Please describe your question bit more

Comment: Are you sure this is a php related issue? I would expect a standard format to use a fixed format for timestamps so that all software components interchanging such data can understand what is meant. A free format in a standard does not make much sense. I would expect it is up to the visualization layer to format the exchanged data such as the user configured.

Comment: Actually it is not a php related issue but i am wonder to know is their any php function to change the format(which means displaying time and date instead of date and time).

Comment: @AlokKumarMishra Now my ICS  file showing date and time but i want it to show time and date. Didi you understand?

Comment: Facing same issue please suggest some answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong place. The format for date and time in ics files is fixed and defined by the iCalendar specification (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 ).
It is up to the application that consume those ics files to display the dates in whatever format they choose to.